# Login is only supported from http:// or https:// URLs. Please host your page in a web

Tags: html, authentication, windows-phone-8

I downloaded a simple html 5 application from the windows mobile services.

I want to use this in a windows phone 8 html5 application and I want to authenticate against google/facebook etc.

I tried to follow the steps with the post here "Azure mobile login problem in PhoneGap app". Inserted the latest Cordova (3.0.0) js file. Perhaps there are more steps I should follow?? there are lots of files to chose from from this download.

When I try to launch this application through the "Emulator WVGA 512MB", I get the following error. "Login is only supported from http:// or https:// URLs. Please host your page in a web"

Can I implement and test the login through the emulator like this? If so what steps do I need to take? I am using Visual studio 2012

I just want to get a simple authentication example to google going in "Windows phone 8 html5" that I can test on my local machine.

Comment: This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248460/no-windows-azure-for-my-html5-game/23293220#23293220