# No windows azure for my html5 game?

Tags: html, azure

Locally on my computer I have created a game in HTML5 (html+javascript). Its one html file that lies on my desktop and runs in Chrome and edit in notepad :).

What I want to do is to connect to Azure as I want to store player score in my game. As I mentioned it runs in chrome, locally right now (file:///path/to/file.html) but in the end I want to release this game to Windows Phone and Android, where I might wrap it in Phonegap, if possible ill drop it if I dont really need it.

So, I have my file on the desktop here and added the link to MobileServices.Web-1.1.0.min.js, and call

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://asd123.azure-mobile.net/', 'foo');
```

When I run this, I get the errormessage:

```
Login is only supported from http:// or Https:// URLs. Please host your page in a web server.
```

Now, I can solve this by running this in IIS rather from my desktop, but I then wonder, what will happen when I push the application onto a device, like Windows Phone? Would it work? Or would I get the same problem there, as I guess the phone HTML5 application is not an webserver and runs the page in a webserver?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.

It may work with phonegap if hosted in a web context but it doesn't appear to work if hosted on a device (which I should imagine is the primary reason for using phonegap).

It looks like the following line of code prevents any calls being made from code that is hosted on a devices filesystem:

```
if(n+="?completion_type="+a+"&completion_origin="+encodeURIComponent(u),!(u&&(u.indexOf("http:")===0||u.indexOf("https:")===0))){c="Login is only supported from http:// or https:// URLs. Please host your page in a web server.",r(c,null);return}
```

If I comment out this line it still doesn't work - I suspect because in a web context it opens another window which you may not be able to do in a native Web View?

I'd be delighted if somebody were able to tell me that I was wrong or that I've just missed out something simple! Otherwise it would have saved me a lot of time and frustration of trying to get this working on mobile devices if it had been made clear in the quick starts. :)